# Using rally-api (ruby) how do you get the State value of a porftfolio item ?

Tags: rally

Using the rally-api I have been trying to access the portfolio kanban state value of items eg.

features.each do |feature|
    puts feature.State # also tried feature.State.Name
...
end

But this always return an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

this looks to be a back end WSAPI change that is coming.  PI states are going to become readable via the wsapi in 1.37, but they are not currently returned when you query for Portfolio Items.  When wsapi 1.37 comes out, if you pass :version => 1.37 to the config to rally_api, you should then be able to get it in the fetch string.

Answer (score 0):

It is easily accessed by using "feature.State.Name". However, in the Ruby toolkit, these fields are all lowercase, with Pascal-cased field names using underscores(_) to represent the casing. It should be, in this case:

```
put feature.state.name
```

and in a more complex case (PlannedRemovalDate):

```
put feature.planned_removal_date
```

Hope this helps.